# How to validate a form in light box?

Tags: php

I Added a form into light box.  I have to validate the form input and send an email with details entered in it. I did that, and it is working fine. But the problem is, that after I added the form in light box, the validation is not working, but the email is being sent. I need to validate the form in light box.

Does anyone know how to do this? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this XHTML 1.1 validation problem simply edit the following line in the Lightbox 2 plugin file named lightbox2.php under the "autoexpand_rel_wlightbox" function:

from:

```
$replacement    = '$1 rel="lightbox['.$post->ID.']">';
```

to:

```
$replacement    = '$1 rel="lightbox_'.$post->ID.'">';
```

character `[` is not allowed in the value of attribute `rel`